# Why doesn't the '\n' performs a new line in this situation?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting some text from a database, so I want to view them in a TextBox object. The text in the DB has \n character to represent a new line, but when I bind the text to the TextBox, the \n still appear without being transformed to new lines!

I've tried the "\r\n" instead with no results!

What's wrong!

Comment: TextBox in Win Forms or a web control?

Comment: Have you tried Enviroment.NewLine?

Comment: Do you have MultiLine property set to true?

Comment: Yes, MultiLine is set to true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the string in the debugger, I'm willing to bet that it has an `\\n` in it, not an `\n`. `\\n` will be displayed as \n, but `\n` will be displayed as a newline

```
string s = "Hello\\nWorld";  // Displays 'Hello\nWorld'

s = "Hello\nWorld";          // Displays 'Hello
                             //           World'
```

Comment: I don't see the difference with "\n" vs. "\n". Typo or something?

Comment: Yeah, the formatting automatically translated my "\\n" to an "\n" for some reason. Fixed.

Comment: The double-slash is .NET's way of representing the \ character, whereas the \n is .NET's way of representing the newline character. So if a user entered the text "\n" into the database, the database actually thinks he/she meant to enter a \ character with an n character. The database won't recognize it as a newline and will instead interpret it as "\\n".

Comment: How could I stop that transformation. 
I want to have a new line.

Comment: Depends on the software you're using to edit the database. What software are you using? Can you hold down shift and press enter? Sometimes that does it.

Comment: Or you could explicitly do a string.Replace("\\n", "\n"), but that would prevent your users from being able to enter text the way they want. Like if they entered text such as "prev\next".

Comment: There is NO software, There is a stored procedure that append some text with others putting '\n' between them. And the ADO.NET bind them to a TextBox in a C# WinForm, Thanks for your help @Phil

Comment: OK, I'll Try to use the Replace solution now, Thanks again

Comment: Worked Perfect ;)
Thanks @Phil